# Ansible windows client or host with Ansible linux server? Possible?

Tags: windows, client, infrastructure, ansible

I am using `Ansible` for some infrastructure management problem for my project. I achieved this task using a Linux client like say to copy a bin file from Ansible server and install it on a client machine. This involves tasks in my playbooks using normal Linux commands like ssh, scp, ./bin etc.,

Now I want to achieve the same in a windows client. I couldn't find any good documentation to try it out. If anyone of you have tried using Ansible with Windows client then it would be great if you could share the procedures or prototype or any piece of information to start with and progress further on my problem.

Comment: One of the goals of ansible is **NOT** to have to install it on your managed machines. As one answer states, configure your Windows host, add that host to your inventory (typically hosts file) and manage it from your Linux (control) host.

Answer (score 5):

Starting in version 1.7, Ansible also contains support for managing Windows machines. This uses native powershell remoting, rather than SSH.  See the Ansible documentation website for details on [Windows support for Ansible](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_windows.html).

Comment: You can find detailed instructions on how to setup Ansible to manage Windows machines at this link. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!profile/ansible-project/APn2wQe4vzr7Onq4GTxy-SEr1AyDCiwQkSTc3iCS1tMtdz-400DSFtExdniU01Y9BEgQW3yxDXgb/ansible-project/DJqUWVnH5Go/wW1jTPh5BwAJ.

Comment: The link above is out of date.  Check [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/ansible-project/skinnedknuckles%7Csort:date/ansible-project/3uSUemHNGsY/odRqM_E5BQAJ) for detailed instructions on how to setup Ansible to manage Windows machines.

Answer (score 4):

There's no built-in Windows support for Ansible today. If you search the mailing list, you'll find some references to people having some minimal success with things like CygWin. You should probably check out the mailing list and stay tuned.

Comment: oh! thats sad! I really looking forward for ansible with windows support. If the, it is a great tool for my problem. I am trying using CygWin now but fetl is there a buildin support. Can you share the mailing list?

Answer (score 1):

Ansible Windows support (including Azure) has been extended a great deal in 2.2 which released in June. https://www.ansible.com/blog/ansible-2.1 For what it's worth, I've also released a [course on Pluralsight](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/ansible-windows-getting-started) for managing Windows targets with Ansible

Answer (score 0):

You can use powershell remoting. But i'm using SSH with Cygwin installed in windows so that the same linux code will work smoothly in windows as well.